# Why is vba always returning No Error when input given is wrong?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a small macro which will traverse through all cells in worksheet and test a column for a particular regex. I have written a simple regex just to compare if the input is string; if it is then it should ignore it else it should format the cell as red. The expected output is that the cell with wrong content should get colored. However, VBA processes every content and pass every incorrect entry as correct.

Here is my code:

```
 Dim RegEx As Object
 Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

       With RegEx
                .Pattern = "/^[A-Za-z]+$/"
                .Global = True
                .IgnoreCase = True

                If .Test(cell_value) Then
                    Cells.Item(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                    MsgBox "Error" + cell_value
                Else
                    MsgBox "No error" + cell_value
                End If
            End With
```

It always returns "No error" even for incorrect input. Any hints?

Comment: First, I don't think VBScript RegExp syntax uses `/` character to delimit the regex patern. Second, in your code if the pattern is found, test will be true and Error will be returned, that seems the inverse of what you explained to want.

Comment: @VincentG Yes you are correct. VB RegExp doesnt use / character to delimit regex and yes you got it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware, that in your example every cell cantoning pattern would be marked as an error, right? To be more specific, if in your example `.Pattern = "A"`, every cell with letter `A` Or `a` (thanks to `IgnoreCase = True`) would be marked as an error, and rest not.

If that is what you intended, something must be wrong with your pattern. The script you posted works fine for me.

Comment: The pattern that I used was incorrect in some aspect. Took some reference from @VincentG's comment However, it gives me some error while formatting cells. I will resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional formatting (ie without code)

As an example this conditional format returns *TRUE* only if the string contains A-Z

> A is 65
>   B is 90

So the test is whether each character has a value between 64 & 90 by comparing the sum of these tests to the length of the string.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>64)), --(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<91))=LEN(A1)
```

I wrote this back in 2004 for another problem, someone like Barry Houdini may have a better solution using the new functions in Xl2013 and xl2016.

Comment: IMHO this is a good suggestion. However, I have now completed my code. Thanks anyway for the humble suggestion.